# add static string to each element in a PANDAs column with multiple strings

Tags: python, pandas

I have some content that looks like this in a dataframe, 'df'.

`**column_name**    **data_type**
data            action , is_enabled , is_system , name , packa...
data            buckets availableBytes , totalBytes , utc
data            discharge
data            buckets failures , hour , success
data            country , dnssuffix , store`

I'd like to have a new column where I can attach 'data.' string to each element in the comma separated strings, in df['data_type']. 
So, for instance in the first row, I'd have a new column based off df['data_type'], named df['elements']. It would contain values

```
data.action, data.is_enabled, data.is_system, data.name,
```

etc...

I'm having difficulty creating this new column? With the code below.

```
df['elements'] = ['data' + s for s in df['data_type']]
```

Comment: that's because data_type is a series of lists, you need to do nested list comprehension or expand your columns

Comment: what @Yuca said, plus try creating the array `elements`, and then adding it as a column to the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for a list comprehension and `str.join`

```
[', '.join(map(lambda x: '.'.join([n, x]), t.split(', '))) for n, t in zip(df.column_name, df.data_type)]
```

Outputs

```
['data.action , data.is_enabled , data.is_system , data.name , data.packa',
 'data.buckets availableBytes , data.totalBytes , data.utc',
 'data.discharge',
 'data.buckets failures , data.hour , data.success',
 'data.country , data.dnssuffix , data.store']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the array first:

```
elements_array = [['data.' + s for s in data_type] for data_type in df['data_type']]
```

Then adding it as a column to the dataframe:

```
df = df.assign(elements=elements_array)
```